# where is the class org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI located?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to import  `org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI`, but could not find which `JAR` contains it?

I am new to Eclipse rcp.
Will be very thankful if someone give me a hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

org.eclipse.ui.workbench_*.jar